# Using yii2's gridview with a normal array of data

Tags: php, yii2

I have an array of data very similar to this

```
[
    'name'=>'mark',
    'age'=> '21'
    'height'=> '190 cm'
]
```

I searched Google and all the results i found were using an active record object.

How do i use the gridview with an array of this sort?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use ArrayDataProvider (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/ArrayDataProvider.php)

```
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $yourArray,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['id', 'username', 'email'],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: i did it the same way and was going to post the answer, thanks.

Comment: thanks for a great answer, but here how to pass filter params ??