# Using ArrayDataProvider in Yii2 gridview and id in actions

Tags: gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I want to use arrayDataProvider in gridview in yii2. I have followed this question:

[Using yii2's gridview with a normal array of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848585/using-yii2s-gridview-with-a-normal-array-of-data)

now my array is displayed in the gridview but the id parameter in delete/edit/view link in the grid is the index of data in array which is not valid id.

How can I pass the real id to these actions?

---

Edited:

My sample array is like this:

```
$data = [
         23 => [
                'id' => 4,
                'title'=>'mark',
                'parentName'=> '21',
                'description'=> '190 cm'],
         18 => [
                'id'=>6, 
                'title'=>'aaa',
                'parentName'=> 50,
                'description'=> '190 cm'],
         40 => [
                'id'=> 8, 
                'title'=>'nnn',
                'parentName'=> '34',
                'description'=> '190 cm'],
            ];
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, can you please answer this ?

Comment: @981 [Gridview with ArrayDataProvider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmqznDvKR7g&list=PLK757tmJ34tNGMy5uzD-Gn_wpjavHFbon)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `key` property I guess!

```
/**
 * @var string|callable the column that is used as the key of the data models.
 * This can be either a column name, or a callable that returns the key value of a given data model.
 * If this is not set, the index of the [[models]] array will be used.
 * @see getKeys()
 */
public $key;
```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/ArrayDataProvider.php

Comment: I paste my sample array with keys

Comment: I am having the same problem, can you please answer this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `key` property, here is an example

```
    $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $data,
        'key' => 'Review_ID',
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);
```